# Styling JSF ICEFaces ace:dialog

Tags: html, jsf, css, icefaces

Can anyone tell me how do I add my own style to a `ace:dialog` component?
It gives a `styleClass` attribute. but this `ace:dialog` has its own styles too.
I'm not a good css guy, so can you help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you just looking for the different attribute names for the ace:dialog if so check out this link http://www.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/20564.page#sthash.wmCHmNhd.dpbs

Comment: I can help you but i also need to know which version your using, as im looking into the different documentation on this im noticing a lot of styling options for different versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite an obvious way is to use code inspector of any browser, preferrably Firebug of Firefox, inspect HTML markup generated by your UI Component Suite and CSS styles. This way you will be able to override the CSS you want easily.

More closely to the question, [`<ace:dialog>`](http://res.icesoft.org/docs/v3_latest/ace/tld/ace/dialog.html) tag from [showcase example](http://icefaces-showcase.icesoft.org/showcase.jsf?grp=aceMenu&exp=dialogBean)

```
<ace:dialog id="dialog"
            header="A sample dialog overview example"
            widgetVar="sampleDialog"
            closable="false"
            modal="true"
            draggable="false"
            showEffect="clip"
            hideEffect="fade"
            width="400">
    <h:form>...</h:form>
</ace:dialog>
```

shows the following HTML markup and styles:

```
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-resizable"
     style="display: block; z-index: 1002; outline: 0px none; position: absolute; height: auto; min-width: 150px; width: 400px; top: 409.5px; left: 488px;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-dialog_main">
    <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
        <span id="ui-dialog-title-dialog_main" class="ui-dialog-title">A sample dialog overview example</span>
    </div>
    <div id="dialog_main" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" 
         style="width: auto; min-height: 0px; height: auto;" scrolltop="0" scrollleft="0">
        <form>...</form>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
    ...
</div>
```

So, the inspection tells us about the following styles:

- `ui-dialog` for the base `<div>`;
- `ui-dialog-titlebar` for the header container;
- `ui-dialog-title` for the text in the header;
- `ui-dialog-content` for the dialog content `<div>`.

Change CSS in inspector to achieve what you want and follow BalusC's example on how to override predefined theme CSS with your custom styles from [How do I override those classes defined in primefaces.css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-those-classes-defined-in-primefaces-css/8774997#8774997) question.